# Comparing time of day on day of week to time of day on day of week

Tags: python, datetime, date-comparison

Is there a straightforward way to test whether `now` is between Friday, 5pm and Sunday, 5pm, of the same week?

This attempt returns `False` because it does not compare `now.time()` relative to either `now.isoweekday() >= 5` or `now.isoweekday() <= 7` being `True` first.

```py
[in]:
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now)
(now.isoweekday() >= 5 and now.time() >= datetime.time(17, 0, 0, 0)) and (now.isoweekday() <= 7 and now.time() <= datetime.time(17, 0, 0, 0))

[out]:
2022-12-17 10:00:32.253489

False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially the condition you're looking for is: after 5pm on Friday, any time Saturday, or before 5pm on Sunday.  That's easy to express:

```
(now.isoweekday() == 5 and now.time() >= datetime.time(17, 0, 0, 0)
    or now.isoweekday() == 6
    or now.isoweekday() == 7 and now.time() <= datetime.time(17, 0, 0, 0)
)
```

The other option would be something like:

- figure out what calendar week `now` falls within
- generate the bounds of the weekend for that calendar week
- test whether `now` is between those bounds

but I think that's actually more complicated than the above if you're just testing this one condition; an approach like that would make more sense if it was part of a repeated pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

def is_weekend_time(my_datetime):
  if (my_datetime.isoweekday() == 5):
    return datetime.time(17, 0, 0, 0) <= my_datetime.time()
  if (my_datetime.isoweekday() == 6):
    return True
  if (my_datetime.isoweekday() == 7):
    return my_datetime.time() < datetime.time(17, 0, 0, 0)
  return False

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now)
print(is_weekend_time(now))

print()
friday_before = datetime.datetime(2022,12,16,16,59,59)
print('Friday Before')
print(friday_before)
print(is_weekend_time(friday_before))

print()
friday_after = datetime.datetime(2022,12,16,17,00,00)
print('Friday After')
print(friday_after)
print(is_weekend_time(friday_after))

print()
saturday = datetime.datetime(2022,12,17,16,59,59)
print('Saturday')
print(saturday)
print(is_weekend_time(saturday))

print()
sunday_before = datetime.datetime(2022,12,18,16,59,59)
print('Sunday Before')
print(sunday_before)
print(is_weekend_time(sunday_before))

print()
sunday_after = datetime.datetime(2022,12,18,18,00,00)
print('Sunday After')
print(sunday_after)
print(is_weekend_time(sunday_after))
```

---

```
2022-12-17 16:01:40.826755
True

Friday Before
2022-12-16 16:59:59
False

Friday After
2022-12-16 17:00:00
True

Saturday
2022-12-17 16:59:59
True

Sunday Before
2022-12-18 16:59:59
True

Sunday After
2022-12-18 18:00:00
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach by actually comparing the datetime

```py
now = datetime.datetime.now()
weekday = now.isoweekday()
print(now, weekday)
upper_bound = (now + datetime.timedelta(days=7 - weekday)).replace(
    hour=17, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0
)
lower_bound = (now - datetime.timedelta(days=weekday - 5)).replace(
    hour=17, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0
)
print(upper_bound, upper_bound.isoweekday())
print(lower_bound, lower_bound.isoweekday())

lower_bound <= now < upper_bound
```

```
2022-12-18 00:37:56 7
2022-12-18 17:00:00 7
2022-12-16 17:00:00 5
True
```

It is actually better if you apply replace function before calculating the bound but this would be easier to understand (and more customizable)

EDIT:

Well, as I see some comment about readability, I've updated with slightly longer but more readable version

```py
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now, now.isoweekday())

def weeekday_to_datetime(now, target_weekday, target_hour):
    target_date = now + datetime.timedelta(days=(target_weekday - now.isoweekday()))
    return target_date.replace(hour=target_hour, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)


lower_bound = weeekday_to_datetime(now, target_weekday=5, target_hour=17)
print(lower_bound, lower_bound.isoweekday())

upper_bound = weeekday_to_datetime(now, target_weekday=7, target_hour=17)
print(upper_bound, upper_bound.isoweekday())

lower_bound <= now < upper_bound
```

```
2022-12-18 02:08:47 7
2022-12-16 17:00:00 5
2022-12-18 17:00:00 7
True
```

Comment: @Jason: This is unreadable. I know you're just a beginner, but trust me: You should always prefer readable code over clever code like this.

Comment: Fair point.  On the basis of Stats and Reputation favouring @JimG. I will change my accepted answer.

Comment: Actually, @Samwise's stats suggest they are also trustworthy, and their answer I find a bit more straightforward and readable based on my particular use case, so I will adjust accepted answer yet again.

Comment: @Jason I've added more readable version just in case. As the function itself might be useful for you.

Comment: @NoThIng: No disrespect... It's just that if you checked this into your company's repository... A year from now, nobody would understand your usage of timedelta.